How to capture the event when clicking the pinned icon in a Chrome extension and open a new window?
I am developing a Chrome extension and want to capture the event when the user clicks on the pinned icon. My goal is to load my extension app in a new window upon clicking the icon.
Problem
I tried the following code, which works only when I click the refresh button:
background.ts
async function openPopupWindow() {
  const { popupWindowId } = await chrome.storage.local.get("popupWindowId");
  if (popupWindowId) {
    try {
      await chrome.windows.update(popupWindowId, { focused: true });
      return true;
    } catch (e) {}
  }
  const popupUri = `popup.html`;
  const popup = await chrome.windows.create({
    url: popupUri,
    type: "popup",
    width: 350,
    height: 600,
  });
  await chrome.storage.local.set({
    popupWindowId: popup.id,
  });
  return false;
}

Then I tried this code, but it does not work:
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  console.log('i am from here');
  chrome.windows.create({
    url: 'popup.html',
    type: "popup",
    width: 350,
    height: 600
  });
});

*manifest.json *
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "My extension description",
  "permissions": [
    "storage", "tabs"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/icon16.png",
      "48": "images/icon48.png",
      "128": "images/icon128.png"
    }
  }
}

How can I properly capture the event when clicking the pinned icon and open a new window with my extension app? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

You should check the console for errors, but I think the issue is because you cannot declare an action default popup in manifest and in the meantime define an action onclick event.
Also function openPopupWindow is never called so you could comment out its code to start with.
